# How to Map the results of Sql query onto Objects in Net Core2?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

How can I map the results of a SQL command into a class object in Net Core, with
SqlCommand() or FromSql()? Can someone update this answer for Net Core, or is the syntax still the same?

[How can I map the results of a sql query onto objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270999/how-can-i-map-the-results-of-a-sql-query-onto-objects)

Comment: What issue are you facing while using the approach suggested in that question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With EntityFramework Core, you simply use `yourDbContextInstance.Set<T>().FromSql("your sql statement");`
Where `T` is your class.
However, your sql MUST return all the properties on your class.

See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) for more details on this.